# Replace win10 Explorer shell with win7 shell

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, shell, windows-explorer

Seems pretty dumb, such question seems not to have any lead across google known internet. For me personally, win10 shell looks extremly overhelming in resource consumption (with no reason at all), while win7 shell is much friendly I would like to replace shell to those I`ve used to. I believe there`s much else, who also will like that.
How it might be possible?

Comment: Have you looked at the [classic shell](http://www.classicshell.net/)?  Also, bashing Microsoft "M$" isn't a very smart way to get people who like their products to help you.  Use your brain.

Comment: Without a third party app, there is no native way to change Explorer.  Have you considered giving it a chance?  It works very well once you adapt to it. I have been using Windows 10 for a half decade and do not notice the Explorer interface any more.

Comment: I often make new installs of win10 to new notebooks and always notice wthat it takes for shell to popup context menu for apps in taks bar and alike. It may take a minute, depending on model, if even show up. Not to mention a start menu. So it is hard for me to say someone ever tried to optimize it. Well, that`s a reason for me to ask this question.

Comment: If you install windows 10 a lot, consider slipstreaming the install medium with your options inside. Look for NTLite.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use Windows 7 shell on Windows 10.

However, you may use Open Shell, which is an open-source, customizable replacement shell.

If you're not interested in using the source code and just want to download and use it, there's an installer link on the same page.

[image]
https://github.com/Open-Shell/Open-Shell-Menu